# How resolve issue with background-image linear-gradient?

Tags: sass, background-image

I am using scsslint which involves  SpaceBetweenParens as 1

and I am using this which does not work because of scsslint

```
@include background-image( linear-gradient ( $tt-white, $tt-light-grey ) );
```

If i remove the spacing, it will work but it will give me scsslint errors
"Expected 1 space between parentheses instead of 0":

```
@include background-image( linear-gradient($tt-white, $tt-light-grey));
```

Any help?

Comment: Actually I was thinking of using scsslint commented code to ignore this error

Answer (score 0):

The "Expected 1 space between parentheses instead of 0" error is due to the space before `linear-gradient` in your code. You should use:

```
@include background-image(linear-gradient($tt-white, $tt-light-grey));
```

See also: https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint/blob/master/lib/scss_lint/linter/README.md#spacebetweenparens